# get the parent count of xml and process the each parent to get the childs using java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have to get the parent count of XML and the parent value is used for to get the child nodes.

Below is my code in java

```
   File inputFile = new File("D:\\bestxml.xml");
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
  dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  XPathExpression expr = null;

 XPath xpath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 expr = xpath.compile("//itm/itm/itm/itm/itm[@type]");
 Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;

 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
 Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
 Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
 String typ=element.getAttribute("type");

  if(typ=="grade")
        {
            typ="grade";
        }
        else if(typ=="course")
        {
            typ="course";
        }
        if("grade".equals(typ))
        {
        }
    System.out.println(" Valueaa: "+nodeList.getLength());
   for(int a=0; a<nodeList.getLength(); a++){
  NodeList childList = nodeList.item(a).getChildNodes();


   }
```

Am getting nodelist length as 20 but i can't get the parent node value alone.

Please any one suggest.

the xml is below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ab_rsp status="ok">


-<itm title="United States" guid="04570A9A-6066-11E2-BB55-FF519035903F" type="country">


-<itm title="Arizona" guid="A83274AC-901A-11DF-A622-0C319DFF4B22" type="authority">


-<itm title="Academic Standards" guid="9935C580-C0DA-11DA-80AA-DCC515614119" type="document">


-<itm title="Technology" guid="E3E0AD06-FC32-11D9-8407-9AE6FB2C8371" type="subject">

<meta name="year">2000</meta>


-<itm title="Readiness (Kindergarten)" guid="001DCFCC-2A74-11D8-A1A9-EB97E8AED672" type="grade">

<meta name="grade" lo="K" hi="K"/>


-<itm guid="929A5FA4-29E4-11D8-9FDA-DEE83CF00340" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Fundamental Operations and Concepts</meta>


-<itm guid="92A019DA-29E4-11D8-94F3-918A2ADD362B" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Communicate about basic technology components using developmentally appropriate and accurate terminology</meta>


-<itm guid="92A2E14C-29E4-11D8-9510-E88CF3390259" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use basic vocabulary related to the use of technology (e.g., mouse, keyboard, monitor, toolbar, menu, window, folder, icon, spreadsheet, word processor, cassette player, CD player versus DVD versus video tape, video camera)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92A5BFAC-29E4-11D8-B459-9A03B60B3918" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Identify the components of a computer (e.g., mouse, keyboard, monitor, CPU, printer)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92A89C36-29E4-11D8-80CB-9286DFCA4E08" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use input devices and output devices successfully to operate computers, VCRs, audiotapes, and other technologies</meta>


-<itm guid="92AB7870-29E4-11D8-81C8-FBD15B9102AD" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate start up and shut down procedures of basic technology components (e.g., computers, tape recorders, cassette players, VCRs)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92AE5900-29E4-11D8-BADC-9BE3FF051872" type="standard">

<meta name="num">1T-R2.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use devices to complete a task (e.g., mouse, keyboard, printer, remote control, microphone)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92B11F50-29E4-11D8-8666-D70924C27789" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Social, Ethical and Human Issues</meta>


-<itm guid="92B9B4EE-29E4-11D8-8819-C3322442EC44" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Work cooperatively and collaboratively when using technology in the classroom</meta>


-<itm guid="92BCA960-29E4-11D8-A217-F8D5963215AE" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate respect for other students while using technology (e.g., take turns, share resources)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92BF7104-29E4-11D8-9926-9EF61CBC1B4F" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Demonstrate appropriate behavior (e.g., use only your documents and folders)</meta>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92C24E38-29E4-11D8-91F7-D0E3C7F2A956" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Practice responsible use of technological devices</meta>


-<itm guid="92C52BD0-29E4-11D8-9F50-8FC6DBAC1404" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Operate equipment to ensure equipment is unharmed (e.g., do not bang on keys; no food or objects near equipment; care for disks and CD-ROM; use proper shut down procedures)</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92C8072E-29E4-11D8-A2CE-8EBA3106B953" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Recognize that damaging school equipment is destroying public property</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92CAE4DA-29E4-11D8-8F74-80A2BA5F84A1" type="standard">

<meta name="num">2T-R2.PO 3</meta>

<meta name="descr">Recognize that changing someone’s work without permission is unacceptable</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92EA3CCC-29E4-11D8-A09B-DF874AC58F3F" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R</meta>

<meta name="descr">Technology Productivity Tools</meta>


-<itm guid="92CDC29A-29E4-11D8-9E76-C7CA8D85B9B7" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Use technology drawing tools for communicating and illustrating</meta>


-<itm guid="92D92248-29E4-11D8-B2AD-9AD0B7A1AB7B" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1.PO 1</meta>

<meta name="descr">Using a drawing program, create a picture story with support from teacher, family members or student partners</meta>

</itm>


-<itm guid="92D644BA-29E4-11D8-8BF2-D14836F4F6A1" type="standard">

<meta name="num">3T-R1.PO 2</meta>

<meta name="descr">Using a drawing program, add name and letters to illustrations</meta>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</itm>

</ab_rsp>
```

Comment: the minus signs at the start of the lines in the xml doc are a feature of your editor. they are not part of the xml doc and invalidate it

Comment: what is the expected output? what is "parent node value alone"?

Comment: parent node is type="grade"

Comment: to get looking at the xpath expression, you are fetching list of attributes, so their parent is the element 
the parents of this list  `"//itm/itm/itm/itm/itm[@type]"` is this `"//itm/itm/itm/itm/itm"` no?

Comment: you show such good knowldge of xpath and you can't figure the correct expression to get the list you want?

Comment: please note you should check String equality using `equals` method, not `==` operator

Comment: am not ASKING YOU TOO CORRECT MY CODE @ SHARONBN, i need a suggestion to get the parent node

Comment: @ MohankumarV, you're welcome. if indeed this is a paste of your code, then the equality error is a glaring bug. second, how about my suggestion to use xpath to get the parent nodes? you defined them as type="grade, so what is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Working in my case:

```
Node parent = doc.getElementsByTagName("your_tag").item(i).getParentNode();

    if (parent.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("your_parent_node")) {
                    parentCnt++;
                }
```

Comment: the xpath expression searches for attribute node